# VBa Compile Error:eXPECTED IDENTIFIER for Private Type ****EMID

Tags: vba

I have decleared the following global variables. These will be used by a module.

However on the line "Private Type ****EMID" I am getting a compile error: Expected identifier.
I have never used these declarations before. Can you please suggest what needs to be done?

```
'- to get Explorer folder
Declare Function SHGetSpecialFolderLocation Lib "shell32.dll" _
    (ByVal hwndOwner As Long, ByVal nFolder As Long, pidl As ITEMIDLIST) As Long
Const CSIDL_WINDOWS = &H24
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" _
    (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal pszPath As String) As Long
'---------------------------
Private Type ****EMID
    cb As Long
    abID As Byte
End Type
'---------------------------
Private Type ITEMIDLIST
    mkid As ****EMID
End Type
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How did the asterisks get there in the first place? Because the Type should read not ****EMID but SHITEMID, for "Shell Item Identifier". Evidently at some point a content filter has replaced a dirty word by a row of asterisks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the asterisks.

EMID and ITEMIDLIST are **Custom Data Types** not global variables.

Here is what your code is doing:

A variable pidl As type ITEMIDLIST is being passed ByRef as a parameter to the Win32 function SHGetSpecialFolderLocation which is found in the dynamic link library (DLL): shell32.dll.  The function will retrieve and/or set values from the pidl variable.  In this case it is setting the values of it.

```
'- to get Explorer folder
Declare Function SHGetSpecialFolderLocation Lib "shell32.dll" _
    (ByVal hwndOwner As Long, ByVal nFolder As Long, pidl As ITEMIDLIST) As Long
Const CSIDL_WINDOWS = &H24
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" _
    (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal pszPath As String) As Long
'---------------------------
Private Type EMID
    cb As Long
    abID As Byte
End Type
'---------------------------
Private Type ITEMIDLIST
    mkid As EMID
End Type
'---------------
```

---

I would use [GetTempName Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0azsy9b(v=vs.84).aspx) of the a FileSystemObject instead of the API calls.

```
Function getTempFileName() As String
    Const TemporaryFolder = 2
    Dim fso
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    getTempFileName = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder).Path & "\" & fso.GetTempName

    Set fso = Nothing
End Function
```